# deploy aws elastic beanstalk has socket error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, boto

I have problem when I deploy django app to aws elastic beanstalk
When running `git aws.push`
There is error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push", line 57, in <module>
  dev_tools.push_changes(opts.get("env"), opts.get("commit"))
File "/Users/John/djangoenv/djangoenv/testsite/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.py", line 196, in push_changes
  self.create_application_version(env, commit, version_label)
File "/Users/John/djangoenv/djangoenv/testsite/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.py", line 184, in create_application_version
  self.upload_file(bucket_name, archived_file)
File "/Users/John/djangoenv/djangoenv/testsite/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.py", line 145, in upload_file
  key.set_contents_from_filename(archived_file)
File "/Users/John/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1355, in set_contents_from_filename
  encrypt_key=encrypt_key)
File "/Users/John/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1286, in set_contents_from_file
  chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
File "/Users/John/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 746, in send_file
  chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
File "/Users/John/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 944, in _send_file_internal
  query_args=query_args
File "/Users/John/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 664, in make_request
  retry_handler=retry_handler
File "/Users/John/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1053, in make_request
  retry_handler=retry_handler)
File "/Users/John/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 923, in _mexe
  request.body, request.headers)
File "/Users/John/djangoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 840, in sender
  http_conn.send(chunk)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 805, in send
  self.sock.sendall(data)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 229, in sendall
  v = self.send(data[count:])
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 198, in send
  v = self._sslobj.write(data)
  socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Why whould this happen??
Please guide me , Thank you

Comment: Does it happen consistently?  It could just be an intermittent network connectivity issue but if it happens every time you try, then something else is going on.

Comment: finally I delete the instance and start a new one. And there is another problem about requirements.txt.I am trying to figure out